# The performance of where clause in dolphindb

Tags: sql-optimization, dolphindb

I have a dfs table stored 5 billion tick data for one year
the table partitioned by 'date' and 'code' , the table schema is as follows

```
date | time | code | bid | ask | bidvol | askvol
2020.03.05 |18:00:00.001 | 20012 | 0.01 | 0.02 | 100 | 200
```

I want to select the data from 9:00 this morning to 16:00 the next afternoon . My code

```
tb = loadTable("dfs://db","tick")
timer select * from tb where code='2993' , concatDateTime(Date,Time) between pair(2020.03.05T07:00:00.000, 2020.03.05T18:00:00.000)
Time elapsed: 161.352 ms,
```

But if I take data of two days , it will be much faster ?

```
timer select * from tb where code='2993' , Date between pair(2020.03.05,2020.03.06)
Time elapsed: 41.813 ms
```

What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to partition pruning in DolphinDB. Check out this link from DolphinDB's manual:

https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?Newtopic10.html